# Issues passing json data to build morris.js plot dynamically

Tags: ajax, json, morris.js

I want to build a morris.js plot dynamically by using ajax, php, and mysql.

i have been searching with no success how to achieve this.

I get the array data successfully with ajax but now i can't pass these data to build the plot.

From the PHP script i get the following json array:

```
[{"concurso":"2736","R1":"7","R2":"24","R3":"27","R4":"39","R5":"45","R6":"52","R7":"12"},{"concurso":"2737","R1":"16","R2":"19","R3":"23","R4":"29","R5":"33","R6":"49","R7":"36"},{"concurso":"2738","R1":"4","R2":"6","R3":"20","R4":"21","R5":"45","R6":"55","R7":"38"},{"concurso":"2739","R1":"5","R2":"16","R3":"17","R4":"24","R5":"41","R6":"47","R7":"36"},{"concurso":"2745","R1":"1","R2":"13","R3":"19","R4":"29","R5":"41","R6":"46","R7":"50"}]
```

Where morris.js *y* is the value after 'concurso', and *ykeys* are the values after *R1*, *R2*, *R3*, ... *R7*.

My jQuery looks like this so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/default_chart_numbers.php",
    cache: false, 
    dataType: "json",
    timeout:3000,
    success : function (data) {

     new Morris.Line({
       // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
       element: 'revancha',
       data: $.parseJSON(data),
       xkey: 'concurso',
       ykeys: ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7'],
       labels: ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7'],
       hideHover: 'auto',
       resize: true
    });
},
error : function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("Error " + errorThrown);
     if(textStatus==='timeout')
         alert("request timed out");
} 
});
```

I can't see the plot. There's nothing. What am i missing?

Well, fortunately i could fix it myself. Here is my working jQuery ☺:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/some_handler.php",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {anyVar: 'specialValue4PHPScriptAndDataBaseFilter'},
    dataType: "json",
    timeout:3000,
    success : function (data) {
    //console.log(data); alert(JSON.stringify(data));

     Morris.Line({
       element: 'TheElementName',
       data: data,
        xkey: 'someID',
        ykeys: ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6'],
        labels: ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
},
error : function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("Error " + errorThrown);
     if(textStatus==='timeout')
         alert("request timed out");
} /*References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746646/ajax-i-cant-get-data-from-php-by-using-json-encode*/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setData()` function on the Morris.Line returned object to update data. Here is a snippet from the morris examples which I've commented. (https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/updating.html)

```js
// build array filled with placeholder data
var nReloads = 0;
function data(offset) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var x = 0; x <= 360; x += 10) {
    var v = (offset + x) % 360;
    ret.push({
      x: x,
      y: Math.sin(Math.PI * v / 180).toFixed(4),
      z: Math.cos(Math.PI * v / 180).toFixed(4)
    });
  }
  return ret;
}
// create the morris chart. 
var graph = Morris.Line({
    element: 'graph',
    data: data(0),
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
    labels: ['sin()', 'cos()'],
    parseTime: false,
    ymin: -1.0,
    ymax: 1.0,
    hideHover: true
});
// update the chart with the new data.
function update() {
  nReloads++;
  // called on the returned Morris.Line object.
  graph.setData(data(5 * nReloads));
  $('#reloadStatus').text(nReloads + ' reloads');
}
setInterval(update, 100);
```